# Dataset Relations - ArgumentNullExpression

Tags: c#, database

I am working on a database through C# on Visual Studio and have run into a problem when trying to add relations. Here is the code:

```
    static void ImportDatabase() {
        OleDbConnection mConn = new OleDbConnection(conn);
        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM ";
        string[] table = { "Artist", "Properties", "Record", "RecordLabel", "Records" };

        dataSet = new DataSet();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                OleDbCommand mCmd = new OleDbCommand((cmd + table[i]), mConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter mDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(mCmd);

                mConn.Open();
                mDA.Fill(dataSet, table[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
                return;
            } finally {
                mConn.Close();
            }

        }

        dataSet.Tables["Artist"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataSet.Tables["Artist"].Columns["ArtistID"] };
        dataSet.Tables["RecordLabel"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataSet.Tables["RecordLabel"].Columns["LabelID"] };
        dataSet.Tables["Record"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataSet.Tables["Record"].Columns["RecordID"] };

        dataSet.Relations.Add("Artist_Records", dataSet.Tables["Record"].Columns["ArtistID"], dataSet.Tables["Artist"].Columns["ArtistID"]);

        dataSet.Relations.Add("Label_Records", dataSet.Tables["Record"].Columns["LabelID"], dataSet.Tables["RecordLabel"].Columns["LabelID"]);


    }
```

The error I get is that "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Data.dll"; what should I do?

Comment: Do all columns exactly exist in tables?

Comment: Yes, I referenced the source database directly when writing the code for the relations

Comment: Check existing of  `dataSet.Tables["Artist"]` in dataset in runtime

Comment: It should exist, as the setting of the primary key worked

Comment: I am super embarrassed...I made a typo in the database itself.